# Sending shell commands to a Linux server over the network

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a tool that will allow me to issue commands over the network without SSH?

For example, I'd like to create a new linux box armed with DVD burners and send this command over the network "growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd -dvd-video dvd" with arguments and send the file to burn. The system would be automated so I need something that can do this easily and efficiently.

Comment: Why do you have a problem with using ssh? It can easily be used to issue the commands, coupled with sftp/ftp for copying the files you want to burn.

Comment: An attempt to preempt your response: I wonder if perhaps it's SSH's password prompt you're trying to avoid? You don't have to use passwords to log in - you can use a public/private key pair. See the man pages for ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id.

Comment: @Jefromi: maybe he's unaware that ssh can be used with single commands, and can be configured to operate securely without prompting for passwords.

Comment: @Jefromi: GET OUT OF MY MIND! :-)

Comment: Ok basically I want one computer to be able to control another over the network but with that specific DVD burning service. I'm not trying to do it manually myself, as I can SSH in. So if I'm trying to have the computer automatically issue the commands (so for example I can have a PHP script that can execute the DVD burn command), is SSH still the most efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient'? It's not manual. You can't be worried about the amount of time it takes to transmit the command. The invocation `ssh <user@host> <command>` is short. Most importantly, it's secure (at least as far as the calling script is). I mean, you could write yourself a totally custom "burn server" which runs on the remote box and listens on a particular port for burn commands according to its own protocol, but that seems like overkill, doesn't it?

Comment: "I mean, you could write yourself a totally custom "burn server" which runs on the remote box and listens on a particular port for burn commands according to its own protocol, but that seems like overkill, doesn't it?" that's precisely what I'm trying to do and was wondering if there's some tool out there that simplifies this.

Comment: Yes, `sshd` is what simplifies this.  You can set up a private/public key pair and then your PHP script can execute `ssh foo@remote "growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd -dvd-video dvd"` - no problem.

Comment: You stated that you wanted to send the command `growisofs ..` over the network. This is entirely different from implementing a standalone 'burn server' on the remote machine. In that case, a client on the local box would connect to a server program on the remote box, and send a command (probably via TCP) which would be translated by the server program into the appropriate burn command to execute. While this would potentially be more robust and elegant, it's also a lot of work. What's wrong with ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment in elaborated answer form.

On the local host, run `ssh-keygen`, most likely saving the key in the default location and not using a passphrase. Next, use `ssh copy-id <user@host>` to copy the public key to the remote host.

For your script, do something like:

```
scp "$FILE_TO_BURN" $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST:"$BURN_DROP_DIR"
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST $BURN_COMMAND
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST rm "$BURN_DROP_DIR/$(basename $FILE_TO_BURN)"
```

Feel free to flesh it out with error detection by capturing the exit status/output of the ssh commands. You might also want to look into doing this without copying the whole file first using something like [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) (packaged by most distros) to mount the directory containing the file to burn over the network.

Comment: Actually I should state my question is how to make a program network accessible. I want people to be able to execute my PHP script and have my PHP script dynamically execute the burning program. So is having PHP executing "scp "$FILE_TO_BURN" $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST:"$BURN_DROP_DIR"
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST $BURN_COMMAND
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST rm "$BURN_DROP_DIR/$(basename $FILE_TO_BURN)" really the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use netcat with a shell bind. This is, of course, quite dangerous if the network is publicly exposed.

[Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=shell+bind+netcat)

Comment: Yea i think this is more into what I was looking for. Thanks.